# Partitioning images based on their white space

Tags: linux, opencv, image-processing

I have lots of images of three objects with a white background separated by white space. For example,

[image]

Is it possible to split this image (and ones like it) into three images automatically?  It would be great if this also worked from the command line.

Comment: Take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).  It may be able to accomplish what you want.

Comment: No, it's on-topic; it is entirely possible to automate this with a script. Are the images always in sets of three, and is the break always in the same place? Look at imagemagick [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) for starters.

Comment: @Emre They are always in sets of three and the break is not always in exactly the same place sadly.

Comment: But is it possible to select two lines, dividing each picture into three, that will work for ALL images, or do you need to set the lines for each picture individually?

Comment: @Emre you need to set the lines individually. So the tool needs to find the white area between the images. Otherwise it would be easy :)

Comment: Image manipulation *with a script* certainly *is* programming. Voting to keep open, although what you're asking is, more or less, "do the hard work for me" - which may or may not pick the interest of answerers.

Comment: I wrote a neat python script for this but I can't post it until the question gets unlocked.

Comment: @Emre Oh, thank you! I would love to see it. Can you post it to http://bpaste.net/ in the meantime?

Comment: @PaulRoub There is a python answer by Emre which he/she would like to post. Is that possible to allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ypnos said, you want to collapse the rows by summation, or averaging. That will leave you with a vector the width of the image. Next clip everything below a high threshold, remembering that high numbers correspond to high brightness. This will select the white space:

[image: The result of clipping the collapsed brightness.]

Then you simply cluster the remaining indices and select the middle two clusters (since the outer two belong to the bordering white space). In python this looks like so:

```python
import sklearn.cluster, PIL.Image, numpy, sys, os.path
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def split(fn, thresh=200):

    img = PIL.Image.open(fn)
    dat = numpy.array(img.convert(mode='L'))
    h, w = dat.shape
    dat = dat.mean(axis=0)
    # plt.plot(dat*(dat>thresh);

    path, fname = os.path.split(fn)
    fname = os.path.basename(fn)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)

    guesses = numpy.matrix(numpy.linspace(0, len(dat), 4)).T
    km = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=guesses)
    km.fit(numpy.matrix(numpy.nonzero(dat>thresh)).T)
    c1, c2 = map(int, km.cluster_centers_[[1,2]])

    img.crop((0, 0, c1, h)).save(path + '/' + base + '_1' + ext)
    img.crop((c1, 0, c2, h)).save(path + '/' + base + '_2' + ext)
    img.crop((c2, 0, w, h)).save(path + '/' + base + '_3' + ext)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    split(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
```

One shortcoming of this method is that it may stumble on images with bright objects (failing to properly identify the white space), or are not separated by a clean vertical line (e.g., overlapping in the composite). In such cases line detection, which is not constrained to vertical lines, would work better. I leave implementing that to someone else.

Comment: This produces "ValueError: The shape of the initial centers ((4, 1)) does not match the number of clusters 2" for me.

Comment: And changing the ", 4)).T" to ", 2)).T" produces "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2"

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum-up over every column in the image and compare the sum with the theoretical sum of all pixels in that column being white (i.e., #lines times 255). Add all columns that match the criterion to a list of indices. In case there is not always a fully clean line between the objects (e.g. due to compression artifacts), you can set a lower threshold instead of the full-white sum.

Now go through your list of indices. Remove all adjacent indices that start at the first column. Also remove all adjacent indices that end at the far right of the image. Create groups of indices that are adjacent to each other. In each group count the number of indices and calculate the mean index.

Now take the two largest groups and take their mean is the index for where to crop.

You can do this in a rather small script in Python with OpenCV, or C++ OpenCV program.