# Getting bounding box information for each character while drawing a string as image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

I want to create a synthetic dataset for character recognition from images. I have a list of words or sequences as text data that I want to draw as images with different fonts and font sizes.

I am using PIL python library for drawing text on images. But the problem is, when the text is drawn in different font sizes, I got stuck to get the coordinates of individual character for drawing the bounding box.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Any idea, code chunk or suggestion of any convenient resource would be very helpful.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you need please, maybe with a diagram? Say you are writing *"hello"* and have just written the `e`, what do you want to find? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the response. I have edited my question and added a visualization for what I am trying to do. Can you please have a look to the question again.

Comment: You're likely going to need some more features than pure PIL, so you could add OpenCV or scikit-image into the mix. Is either, or both, or neither acceptable?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, opencv or scikit-image both are fine. can you please suggest any idea to start with?

Comment: Have a look at my 3 answers here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473372/2836621

Comment: Hey @FarukAhmad, which solution did you end up using, if you don't mind me asking?